# Suggest using Kfold splits or validation_split kwarg in Keras Training?

Tags: machine-learning, keras

In many examples, I see train/cross-validation dataset splits being performed by using a `Kfold`, `StratifiedKfold`, or other pre-built dataset splitter. Keras models have a built in `validation_split` kwarg that can be used for training.

```
model.fit(self, x, y, batch_size=32, nb_epoch=10, verbose=1, callbacks=[], validation_split=0.0, validation_data=None, shuffle=True, class_weight=None, sample_weight=None)
```

(https://keras.io/models/model/)

> validation_split: float between 0 and 1: fraction of the training data to be used as validation data. The model will set apart this fraction of the training data, will not train on it, and will evaluate the loss and any model metrics on this data at the end of each epoch.

I am new to the field and tools, so my intuition on what the different splitters offer you. Mainly though, I can't find any information on how Keras' `validation_split` works. Can someone explain it to me and when separate method is preferable? The built-in kwarg seems to me like the cleanest and easiest way to split test datasets, without having to architect your training loops much differently.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between the two is quite subtle and they can be used in conjunction.

`Kfold` and similar functions in `scikit-learn` will randomly split your data into `k` folds. You can then train models holding out a single fold each time and testing on the fold.

`validation_split` takes a fraction of your data non-randomly. According to the Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/#how-is-the-validation-split-computed) it will take the fraction from the end of your data, e.g. `0.1` will hold out the final 10% of rows in the input matrix. The purpose of the validation split is to allow you to assess how the model is performing on the training set and a held out set at every epoch in the training period. If the model continues to improve on the training set but not the validation set then it is a clear sign of potential overfitting.

You could theoretically use `KFold` cross-validation to construct a model while also using `validation_split` to monitor the performance of each model. At each fold you will be generating a new `validation_split` from the training data.

Comment: This approach (taking always the same part of the data) can sometimes lead (especially for small datasets) to lower loss for the validation dataset than for the training dataset. Likewise, a greater accuracy for the validation set than for the training set. Which can be confusing and counterintuitive.